# rtl8852be | Wifi works but bluetooth doesn't

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, realtek

I do have Realtek controller (rtl8852be) in my HP ProBook 450 15.6 inch G9 Notebook with Ubuntu 20.04, after install the OS I wasn't able to connect to wifi, I installed the driver from https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be, and now I can use my wifi, but bluetooth still doesn't work, I tried to install it's driver from https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be_bt , but it doesn't work for me, following are some information about my system.

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4601 (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 46a8 (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 461d (rev 04)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 464d (rev 04)
00:06.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 463d (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 464f (rev 04)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 461e (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ed (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 51ef (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51e8 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 51e0 (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51be (rev 01)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51bf (rev 01)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 51a8 (rev 01)
00:1e.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51aa (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5182 (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51c8 (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 51a3 (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51a4 (rev 01)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

`lshw -class network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: cc:47:40:1d:9a:4c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8852be driverversion=v1.15.6.0.2-0-gac110bf5.2021102 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.100.26 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:146 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:80900000-809fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 15
       serial: e0:73:e7:dd:85:15
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-94-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:80804000-80804fff memory:80800000-80803fff
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

```
DeviceName: Onboard Ethernet
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1e.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51a8] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8aa1]
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8852be
Kernel modules: 8852be
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:8aa1]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

`rfkill list`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c7e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13fd:1d40 Initio Corporation PHD
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:b85c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05c8:0b06 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`inxi -Fxpmrz && lsusb && lspci && rfkill list all && mokutil --sb-state`

```
Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Machine: Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP ProBook 450 15.6 inch G9 Notebook PC v: N/A serial: <filter>
Mobo: HP model: 8AA1 v: KBC Version 21.61.00 serial: <filter> UEFI: HP v: U85 Ver. 01.07.00
date: 03/24/2023
Battery: ID-1: BAT0 charge: 40.6 Wh condition: 41.4/42.8 Wh (97%) model: Hewlett-Packard Primary
status: Charging
Memory: RAM: total: 15.27 GiB used: 5.69 GiB (37.3%)
RAM Report: permissions: Unable to run dmidecode. Root privileges required.
CPU: Topology: 6-Core model: 12th Gen Intel Core i7-1255U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: N/A
L2 cache: 12.0 MiB
flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 62668
Speed: 915 MHz min/max: 400/4700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 950 2: 725 3: 842 4: 894 5: 914 6: 779
7: 1172 8: 1070 9: 1029 10: 1092 11: 856 12: 955
Graphics: Device-1: Intel vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa
resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes
Audio: Device-1: Intel vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus ID: 00:1f.3
Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.15.0-94-generic
Network: Device-1: Realtek vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rtl8852be v: N/A port: 4000 bus ID: 03:00.0
IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard
driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 bus ID: 04:00.0
IF: enp4s0 state: down mac: <filter>
IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives: Local Storage: total: 2.29 TiB used: 1.72 TiB (75.2%)
ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLQ512HBLU-00BH1 size: 476.94 GiB
ID-2: /dev/sda type: USB vendor: Seagate model: ST2000LM007-1R8174 size: 1.82 TiB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 467.91 GiB used: 275.65 GiB (58.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
ID-2: /boot/efi size: 486.0 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
ID-3: /media/amir/Data_1 size: 319.78 GiB used: 303.47 GiB (94.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
ID-4: /media/amir/Data_2 size: 869.80 GiB used: 661.67 GiB (76.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
ID-5: /media/amir/Data_4 size: 549.31 GiB used: 519.97 GiB (94.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
ID-6: /snap/bare/5 raw size: 4 KiB size: <superuser/root required> used: <superuser/root required>
fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop0
ID-7: /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/34 raw size: 9.4 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop6
ID-8: /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/37 raw size: 14.0 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop21
ID-9: /snap/chromium/2742 raw size: 159.7 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop1
ID-10: /snap/chromium/2749 raw size: 159.7 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop5
ID-11: /snap/code/150 raw size: 308.2 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop2
ID-12: /snap/code/151 raw size: 308.2 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop29
ID-13: /snap/core/16202 raw size: 105.8 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop3
ID-14: /snap/core/16574 raw size: 105.4 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop4
ID-15: /snap/core18/1988 raw size: 55.5 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop9
ID-16: /snap/core18/2812 raw size: 55.7 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop7
ID-17: /snap/core20/2105 raw size: 63.9 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop22
ID-18: /snap/core22/1033 raw size: 74.1 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop12
ID-19: /snap/cups/1024 raw size: 66.5 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop10
ID-20: /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198 raw size: 164.8 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop8
ID-21: /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66 raw size: 219.0 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop11
ID-22: /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93 raw size: 218.4 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop16
ID-23: /snap/gnome-42-2204/141 raw size: 497.0 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop13
ID-24: /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514 raw size: 64.8 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop14
ID-25: /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 raw size: 91.7 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop17
ID-26: /snap/opera/288 raw size: 188.7 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop15
ID-27: /snap/opera/289 raw size: 189.5 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop26
ID-28: /snap/pdftk/9 raw size: 17.8 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop18
ID-29: /snap/scrcpy/399 raw size: 83.0 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop24
ID-30: /snap/snap-store/518 raw size: 51.0 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop19
ID-31: /snap/snap-store/959 raw size: 12.3 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop20
ID-32: /snap/snapd/20290 raw size: 40.9 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop28
ID-33: /snap/snapd/20671 raw size: 40.4 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop25
ID-34: /snap/vlc/3721 raw size: 321.1 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop27
ID-35: /snap/yt-dlp/364 raw size: 126.7 MiB size: <superuser/root required>
used: <superuser/root required> fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop23
Sensors: System Temperatures: cpu: 47.0 C mobo: 25.0 C
Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos: Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
1: deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
2: deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
3: deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
4: deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
5: deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
6: deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
7: deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
8: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
9: deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
10: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
11: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
12: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
13: deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/protonvpn-stable.list
1: deb [arch="all", signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/protonvpn-stable-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable main
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list
1: deb https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/ jessie main
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tomtomtom-ubuntu-woeusb-focal.list
1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tomtomtom/woeusb/ubuntu focal main
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/twingate.list
1: deb [trusted=yes] https://packages.twingate.com/apt/ /
Info: Processes: 350 Uptime: 23m Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.4.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17
inxi: 3.0.38
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c7e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13fd:1d40 Initio Corporation PHD
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:b85c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05c8:0b06 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4601 (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 46a8 (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 461d (rev 04)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 464d (rev 04)
00:06.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 463d (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 464f (rev 04)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 461e (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ed (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 51ef (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51e8 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 51e0 (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51be (rev 01)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51bf (rev 01)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 51a8 (rev 01)
00:1e.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51aa (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5182 (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51c8 (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 51a3 (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51a4 (rev 01)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
SecureBoot disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in terminal

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.15.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-5.15
sudo dkms install btusb/4.1
```

Reboot

Answer (score -1):

From your post, it's hard to tell if you have checked that the bluetooth service is actually running. You can check if your bluetooth service is turned on by running `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service` if it is not you can enable it by running `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service`. For more information please read here. https://discovery.endeavouros.com/audio/bluetooth/2021/03/