# Ubuntu 20.04, MT7922A22M bluetooth not working

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, ubuntu-drivers, mediatek

I have Ubuntu **20.04** with kernel **5.15.0-97-generic** installed alongside a Windows 11 on a HP Omen 16. I have the MT7922A22M PCIe adapter for Wireless and Bluetooth. Both work in windows 11, but Bluetooth doesn't work in Ubuntu. It's using the mediatek/mt7668pr2h.bin firmware as per **modinfo btusb**. But I'm unable to turn on Bluetooth. I've tried both the answers in the below threads, but I've faced some issues with those methods.

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199350/bluetooth-btusb-how-to-replace-module-version-with-a-newer-one
2. [Laptop bluetooth device not being recognised by Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425384/laptop-bluetooth-device-not-being-recognised-by-ubuntu-22-04) (The same issues as his, but in 20.04, I'm facing issues signing the key for the newly build driver)

Now an odd behavior is that, previously I've had two windows 11 alongside this Ubuntu 20.04 and whenever Bluetooth doesn't work I just boot into the second windows 11 (Which I've deleted due to reasons) and boot back into Ubuntu, then the Bluetooth works fine. I have no clear idea about why this is happening. Any insight would be helpful and a solution to this would be relieving. Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Some useful info

1. [lsusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYzOz.png)
2. [modinfo btusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF82Z.png)

Comment: Yes indeed and I've got the bluetooth working.

Comment: If the above link answered your question please click the "Yes" option to the right of "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1503046/300665 would have worked for that and it would rebuild the module for each kernel update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in the thread [Laptop bluetooth device not being recognised by Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425384/laptop-bluetooth-device-not-being-recognised-by-ubuntu-22-04) works like a charm. I've figured the issue with kernel module signing. Now bluetooth is working.

Thanks,
JKR